# Remove Band Separators when exporting CxGridBandedTableView to Excel

Tags: delphi, devexpress, export-to-excel, delphi-2009, tcxgrid

I have a TCxGrid (DevExpress) with a TCxGridDBBandedTableView. This view has 2 bands, and each band has its columns.

I use the ExportGridToExcel (from DevExpress's cxGridExportLink unit), to expot the grid to excel. Example:

**Grid Configuration**

- Band 1:
- => Column A
- => Column B
- Band 2:
- => Column A
- => Column B
- => Column C

**How the excel is being generated:**

- Column A (content of Band 1: Column A)
- Column B (content of Band 1: Column B)
- Column C (empty content, because here is where second band begins)
- Column D (content of Band 2: Column A)
- Column E (content of Band 2: Column B)
- Column F (content of Band 2: Column C)

**How I would like it to be:**

- Column A (content of Band 1: Column A)
- Column B (content of Band 1: Column B)
- Column C (content of Band 2: Column A)
- Column D (content of Band 2: Column B)
- Column E (content of Band 2: Column C)

Is there a way I could configure it not to consider "bands separators" as empty columns when generating excel?

Comment: Developer express are usually really quick and good with their support so that would probably be the best place to ask for help (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). You can also search there for old tickets. A question that sounds similar to yours had the following as a solution "As a workaround in your case you can set the TcxGridBandedTableView.OptionsView.FixedBandSeparatorWidth property to 0."

Comment: Thanks in advance, I submitted a [Ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T226593), if they give me a solution, I post here. Otherwise, you could put this workaround as an answer, since it gives me what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. The problem is that I had these 2 bands, and my second band had **FixedKind** defined with **fkLeft**. I changed it to **fkNone**, and edited his **Position.ColIndex** property to zero (because I wanted it to be the first band). Thanks!